# How to add an existing web application under svn control

Tags: svn, project-management

I start working at an existing project (an web application) that was created by someone else. I would like to put it under version control (using SVN). How can I do that? Do I have to move the project files in a repository, or there is another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have a repository, you can `svn import` the project then checkout a working copy.

```
# Make a new directory in the repo
svn mkdir http://repository.url/repo/newproject
# Import the project to the repo
svn import /local/path/to/project http://repository.url/repo/newproject
```

Then the next step is to checkout the code so you are working with a svn working copy.

```
# Rename or delete the existing code
# to /local/path/to/project.old
svn checkout http://repository.url/repo/newproject
```

At this point, the original local project files are no longer needed. You can delete them if the checked out working version is all in order.

#### Update:

To get the production server to reflect changes you have made and committed from local development, you need to have a working copy on the web server as well.  Use the same process to rename or delete the old code, then checkout a working copy onto the production environment.

After making and committing changes in development, you need to `svn update` on the production server to bring it up to date.

```
# In production...
cd /path/to/project
# Update the production working copy...
svn update
```

**Note**: Make sure your web server is configured to deny access to `.svn` directories!!!

Comment: Thanks Michael for answering. I already did what you suggested but after commiting, no changes where visible in the project. I have the repository on the same server with the project.

Comment: @sica07 What do you mean no changes were visible? Do you mean not visible on the production web server after making changes in your local development?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @sica07 Then you need a checked out working copy on the production server too.  See update above...

Comment: It's working. Thank you, and also thanks for the tip about the .svn permissions